# creating new usercontrols at runtime in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, runtime, user-controls

My situation is that the user is creating an entity on my site which contains the particlars of the driectors of that company, name address etc..

The Director form is a separate user control with the appropriate textboxes etc.

At run time we don't know how many of these directors there will be so I need one to be able to use something like an "ADD DIRECTOR" or "DELETE DIRECTOR" button which will present or delete the another usercontrol to add the additional director.

Currently I am trying to make this happen within a pane of the JQuery Accordion control.

I have looked many places for how to do this but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me where I might find some inforamation about how I can do this?

All the best

Paul

Comment: what did I do to merit a minus vote?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly "adding usercontrols". But I suggest you look at a template engine like this one: http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote/

Comment: This was an excellent answer that I found:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html
It uses W3 DOM script